# Not able to push return of function into vue3 modal

Tags: modal-dialog, vuejs3, v-for

I have a function that is filtering data based upon clickable button (seen in console logs). When I put this array into my modal as a v-for 'loop', I break my button function. Why?  Each time I do this, I get 'undefined' results.  This idea worked fine for displaying table row data based on the skedDatas array.

Function getrowid within /src/pages/courses/ammo04.vue.  Code is at github: https://github.com/EnergeticPixels/catalog

Comment: your button click to run `getrowid($event)` and your v-for are performing **separate, unrelated calls** to your getrowid method.  `v-for="(getrowid, index) in getrowid"` is calling a method that is not getting any event or id data.  It would be expected to break.

Comment: As a side note, you're messing up on some fundamental Vue practices.  For example: `@click.prevent="getrowid($event)" :data-id="skedData.classId"` is unnecessarily complex.  Just do `getrowid(skedData.classId)` and have the method accept the id as the parameter rather than passing the click event and accessing the data attribute...  `const getrowid = (classId) => { ... }`

Comment: @yoduh repo amended. I can see the selected array (line 69/70) from within my getclickedrow function. But when I return that data, I am not able to see it on a console log statement like at my line 74. I am trying to make sure that the array can be acted upon so that I can filter sitePoc array based on key value pairs within the filtered clickedrow function.  Am I using 'return' incorrectly or not targeting the function correctly?

Comment: line 74 won't work because `justPicAClass` is [scoped](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Scope) to the function, it doesn't exist outside of it.  I think I've pieced together what you're trying to accomplish so I've posted an answer that should hopefully help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would not call methods directly in the template of your component. Any time a rerender happens, the method reruns, which is going to cause problems and other side effects if you're not very careful.  I suggest using a ref variable to hold the data.  Being scoped to the entire component, you can use it in both your script and template code without needing to pass it around/return it anywhere.

First, updating the button to pass `classId` as a parameter to the toggleModal function, showing that the use of data attributes is not needed with Vue:

```html
<td><button @click.prevent="toggleModal(skedData.classId)">{{ skedData.contact }}</button></td>
```

```js
const toggleModal = (classId) => {
  getclickedrow(classId);
  modalActive.value = !modalActive.value;
}
```

Passing it again as a parameter to `getclickedrow` and using a ref to hold the result of the array filter (which I would change to [Array.find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) if the expected result is always 1 object, which I think it is...):

```js
const skedfiltered = ref(null);
const getclickedrow = (classId) => {
  skedfiltered.value = skedDatas.find(offering => {
    return offering.classId === classId
  });
};
```

I saw this next code was commented out, but I noticed if made into a [computed property](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/computed.html) it will automatically re-evaluate itself based on the above `skedfiltered` ref, always giving you the desired Poc. This also looks like a better job for Array.find than Array.filter. Just be careful when `skedfiltered` is initially null, finding or filtering won't work (hence the [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) to catch this)

```
// filter sitePoc array for matching clicked contactId
const filteredPoc = computed(() => sitePocs.find(poc => {
  return poc.contactId === skedfiltered.value?.contactId
}))
```

computed needs to be imported, so change the line at the top:

```js
import { ref, computed } from 'vue';
```

Finally, setting the rest of the template code to display all of the data evaluated above:

```html
<ContactInfo v-if="filteredPoc" :filteredPoc="filteredPoc" class='contactInfo' @close="toggleModal" :modalActive="modalActive">
  <h2 class="title has-text-centered is-size-3">{{ filteredPoc.pocTitle }}</h2>
  <p class="">Please contact the following individual(s):</p>
  <ul>
    <li><span class="has-text-weight-bold">Name:</span> {{ filteredPoc.pocName }}</li>
    <li><span class="has-text-weight-bold">Email:</span> {{ filteredPoc.pocEmail }}</li>
    <li><span class="has-text-weight-bold">Commercial Phone 1:</span> {{ filteredPoc.pocPhone1 }}</li>
    <li><span class="has-text-weight-bold">Commercial Phone 2:</span> {{ filteredPoc.pocPhone2 }}</li>
    <li><span class="has-text-weight-bold">DSN:</span> {{ filteredPoc.pocdsnPhone }}</li>
  </ul>
  <div v-if="filteredPoc.altpocName">
    <p class="">Or their alternate:</p>
    <ul>
      <li><span class="has-text-weight-bold">Name:</span> {{ filteredPoc.altpocName }}</li>
      <li><span class="has-text-weight-bold">Email:</span> {{ filteredPoc.altpocEmail }}</li>
      <li><span class="has-text-weight-bold">Commercial Phone 1:</span> {{ filteredPoc.altpocPhone1 }}</li>
      <li><span class="has-text-weight-bold">Commercial Phone 2:</span> {{ filteredPoc.altpocPhone2 }}</li>
      <li><span class="has-text-weight-bold">DSN:</span> {{ filteredPoc.altpocdsnPhone }}</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</ContactInfo>
```

Added `v-if="filteredPoc"` which is for error prevention. Even when the modal is not visible, all elements get rendered to the DOM, and if `filteredPoc` is null (and it is initially), all these elements trying to use it will cause an error, so the `v-if` will prevent that. The `v-if` will evaluate to true by the time modalActive is toggled true, so it should all work out.